# php base64_encode simplified answer

Tags: php

What are practical uses of base64_encode and base64_decode? 
At what particular situations are they used? For example, in terms of security?

What is the usage of using this function when sending an image via a URL like this?

```
echo '<img src="file_viewer.php?file=', base64_encode($dir . '/' . $file), '" alt="', $file, '"/>';
```

Comment: When you have binary data and want to represent it as text, you need to use an encoding like Hex or Base64.

Comment: I think this question is on topic. How can you handle binary data in a safe way? What is encoding/decoding of binary data?

Comment: @Bent on topic but too broad, see eg [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat I agree that the question could be a bit more clear in its focus. The main aim of my comment was to try to stem the flow of auto-downvotes, at least till we see if this can be made a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base64_encode is used to encode binary data including null bytes into a readable string much like hexadecimal notation for numbers.

You can encode anything including a jpg (which is basically a sequence of bytes including possible null bytes). You can encode it when you store a value eg in a database to prevent null bytes messing things up and when you what to display it you decode it.

You might be a little confused by the ability to send an image with php, but the img tag in html just send a request for 'something' (not specifically an image file) to the server, and that request can be served by a piece of php code.

I should probably add that most databases are quite good at storing images as blobs, but if you wanted to include an image in xml or json encoding it would be an easy way to do that. You wouldn't even need to use cdata in xml.

And that hashed passwords often contain null bytes, encoding them allows the storage in databases as strings.

The encode value does take up a bit more space though.